# trying to get information from urls array using cURL, getting bad request

Tags: arrays, curl

my urls array contains like 100 urls, and is getting the information from an API designed for something like that.
Anyway, like 50% of the urls returns

```
400 Bad Request


Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
GET /player/euw/Wolves Deficio/ingame HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1
Host: api.captainteemo.com
Accept: */*
```

the urls are 100% correct, cause when I copy them to my browser, I DO get the info.

Here is my code:

```
function get_data($urls) {
    // spoofing FireFox 2.0
    $useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1";

    $ch = curl_init();

    // set user agent
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
    if(is_array($urls)) {
        $output = array();
        foreach($urls as $url) {
            // set the rest of your cURL options here
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
            //return the transfer as a string 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
            // $output contains the output string 
            array_push($output, curl_exec($ch));
        }
    }
    else {
        // set the rest of your cURL options here
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urls); 
        //return the transfer as a string 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
        // $output contains the output string 
        $output = curl_exec($ch);

    }
    // close curl resource to free up system resources 
    curl_close($ch);    

    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION in a case of redirect

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Try this:

```
<?php

function get_data($urls) 
{
    if ( !is_array( $urls ) ) 
        $urls = array( '0' => $urls );

    $useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1";

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

    $output = array();

    foreach($urls as $url)
    {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
        $output[$url] = curl_exec($ch);
    }

    curl_close($ch);

    return $output;
}

$urls = array(
                'http://www.wikipedia.org/',
                'http://www.stackoverflow.com'
             );

//or single url
//$urls = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com';

print_r ( get_data($urls) );
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I spoofed the user agent instead of using a real one, also didnt repalced " " by "+".